# how to compute all possible combination of column and do summation of values

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

data

```
value   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6  
"text"   0   1    0    1    0    1   
"text"   1   0    0    0    0    0   
"text"   1   1    0    1    0    1   
"text"   0   0    0    1    1    1   
"text"   0   1    1    1    1    1
```

> Requirement

count of value in `c1=2`
count of value in `c2=3`
count of value in `c3=0`
...
etc

count of value in `c1&c2=1`
count of value in `c1&c3=0`
...
etc

count of value in `c1&c2&c3=1`...
all the way to `c1&c2&c3&c4&c5&c6=0`
all the possible combination and count summation of it

Comment: It is not clear from your question what the outcome is that you are looking for. Could you add in an example of your desired outcome with using the current data?

Comment: the out put is as i wrote c1=2 c2=3 ... c1&c2=1    c1&c3=0 ...... c1&c2&c3=1..... all the way to c1&c2&c3&c4&c5&c6=0

Comment: I'm down voting your question because not only did you not attempt to answer the question yourself, provide code attempted, but when I told you I didn't understand your question, while trying to help you, you tell me the question is fine as worded.  Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: sorry for that what meant i need to count the number os  rows that have c1 in it equal to 1 and output a number then do the same for all rows with c2=1 ,c3=1...c6=1 then count all row with c1=1&c2=1 and output a number for all rows with both c1 and c2 is  all the way to c6 and c6 the do the same with three columns c1&c2&c3=1  c1&c2&c4=1 finally to reach c1&c2&c3&c4&c5&c6   hope that clarify what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution which is very easy

> data_raw.groupby(['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

this group the categories and sum them